# Show a table that summarizes json data and total cost when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written an Angular application below. The app asks a user to fill out a form and based on the answers, does some calculations once the user clicks "*Get Quote*" button. When the button is clicked, the user should see a table that summarizes all the info that was inputted and then in the bottom of the table should display the total cost.

My problem is I don't know how to display the summary in table format and I don't know how to display the total cost. I am certain that I am 90% done, just this end part is missing. I have presented my code below:

The **Html** is:

```
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
<div class="row">
    <pre>{{user | json}}</pre>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="company">Company Name*</label><br />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" ng-model="user.company">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="salesp">Salesperson Name*</label><br />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="salesp" placeholder="Salesperson Name" ng-model="user.salesp">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="emailsales">Contact Email*</label><br />
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailsales" placeholder="john.doe@example.com" ng-model="user.emailsales">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="partnum">Number of Part Being Made(Finished Goods)</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id ="partnum" name="partnum" placeholder="Enter # items" ng-model="user.partnum">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>New Files?</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="files" id="files" value="42" ng-model="user.files"> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="files" id="files" value="0"ng-model="user.files"> No

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Rerun Files?</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="oldfiles" value="15" ng-model="user.oldfiles"> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="oldfiles" value="0" ng-model="user.oldfiles"> No

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="shortp">Shortest Dimension on Print Part (inches)</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="shortp" placeholder="Shortest Dim" ng-model="user.shortp">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="longp">Longest Dimension on Print Page (inches)</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="longp" placeholder="Longest Dim" ng-model="user.longp">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="pressnum">Number of Ups on Press Sheet</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="pressnum" placeholder="# Ups" ng-model="user.pressnum">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="shortpress">Number of Short Press Sheet</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shortpress" name="shortpress" placeholder="# Short Press" ng-model="user.shortpress">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="longpress">Number of Long Press Sheet</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="longpress" name="longpress" placeholder="# Long Press" ng-model="user.longpress">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Passes First Side?</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="passfirst" value="Yes" ng-model="user.passfirst"> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="passfirst" value="No" ng-model="user.passfirst"> No

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inkcoverone">Percent of Ink Coverage on First Side</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inkcoverone" name="inkcoverone" placeholder="% Ink Coverage" ng-model="user.inkcoverone">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Passes Second Side?</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="passsecond" value="1" ng-model="user.passsecond"> Yes
        <input type="radio" name="passsecond" value="0" ng-model="user.passsecond"> No

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inkcovertwo">Percent of Ink Coverage on Second Side</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="inkcovertwo" placeholder="% Ink Coverage" ng-model="user.inkcovertwo">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-offset-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block register" ng-click="quoteGenerator()"> GET QUOTE </button>
                </div>
</div>
```

{{total}} //table should go here, not sure how to display user inputs and this total cost

The **JS** file is:

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.quoteGenerator = quoteGenerator;

    function quoteGenerator(){
    let count = $scope.partnum;
    //parseInt(document.getElementById('partnum').value);
    if (count > 0) {
        let size = 0;
        for (var i = 0 ; i < document.getElementsByName('files').length; i++) {
            if (document.getElementsByName('files')[i].checked) {
                    size = parseInt( document.getElementsByName('files')[i].value);
                    break;
            }
            if(size == 42){
                let newcount = count * size;
            } else if(size==0){
                for (var i = 0 ; i < document.getElementsByName('oldfiles').length; i++) {
                    if (document.getElementsByName('oldfiles')[i].checked) {
                        newsize = parseInt( document.getElementsByName('oldfiles')[i].value);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                let newcount= count*newsize;
            }
        }       
    }
    var ink = parseInt(document.getElementById('inkcoverone').value);
    var shortp = parseInt(document.getElementById('shortpress').value);
    var longp = parseInt(document.getElementById('longpress').value);
    var parentsheet = parseInt(document.getElementById('psheetnum').value);
    let inkcost1 = ((longp+shortp)/144)*.19*ink*parentsheet;

    for (var i = 0 ; i < document.getElementsByName('passsecond').length; i++) {
            if (document.getElementsByName('passsecond')[i].checked) {
                    pass2 = parseInt( document.getElementsByName('passsecond')[i].value);
                    break;
            }
    }
    var ink2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('inkcovertwo').value);
    let inkcost2 = ((longp+shortp)/144)*.19*ink2*parentsheet*pass2;

var total = inkcost2+inkcost1+newcount;
}
$scope.total = total;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `document.getElementById` to get the value selected by the user when that value would be available in `$scope.user`?

Comment: So should I replace the document.getElement byId with scope.user.inkcoverone?

Comment: You certainly can. I think you need to do some additional angular research and understand how to leverage it. I realise this doesn't answer your query but it'll make you appreciate the framework much more :).